# Fetch data from Supabase with NodeJS (Error: invalid input syntax for type timestamp)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, supabase

using Supabase JS library to fetch data from my tables. My code works fine if I use directly filter .eq but not with .or for comparing timestamps. I tried different combos such as defined toISOString outside of the function but to no prevail.

Documentation: https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/or

Error:

```
{
  message: 'invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "ts.toISOString("',
  code: '22007',
  details: null,
  hint: null
```

Code:

```
var ts = new Date();
ts.setHours(ts.getHours() - 168)

const supabaseNotifications = async() => {
    let { data, error } = await supabase
    .from('table3')
    .select('*, table1!inner(coin, coin_abr, combo_change, combo_signal, combo_prev_signal), table2!inner(email, created_at, is_subscribed)')
    .eq('table1.combo_change', true)
    .or('created_at.gt.ts.toISOString(),is_subscribed.eq.true', { foreignTable: "table2" })

    if(error) {
        console.error(error)
        return
    }
    console.log(data)
}

supabaseNotifications()
```